# Strange "-12 rep"

Tags: support

So in profile:
[image]

I see "-12" reputation.
However, i don't have recent rep changes, neither positive, nor negative.
What could cause it?

Comment: Check the "show removed posts" checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone upvoted an answer of yours and then un-upvoted it later that same day, giving you -10 and no record on the reputation history.  The other option is from a deleted answer, if that answer had one upvote; this would only be an option if you had not enabled "show removed posts" on the reputation history.

The additional -2 is from the downvote shown.